# getting object by parameter from nested object mongodb spring data jpa

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I have mongodb collection for following documents:

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document
public class Account {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String username;

    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String email;

    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String contact;

    private ConfirmationTokenDetails confirmationTokenDetails;
}

@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document
public class ConfirmationTokenDetails {
    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String confirmationToken;

    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    private LocalDateTime expiredAt;
}
```

Basically all what I want is just get Account entity by confirmationToken attribut which stores in nested ConfirmationTokenDetails object. I tried do that by using following method

```
public interface AccountRepository extends MongoRepository<Account, String> {

    Optional<Account> findByConfirmationTokenDetails_ConfirmationToken(String token);
}
```

but it wasn't working for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Please [edit] your question and add more details: What happens when you run your code, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].